# Disable MathML output of eLyXer

Tags: linux, html, latex, tex, lyx

eLyXer is a standalone LyX to HTML converter. In the resulting file, equations are formatted as MathML, and the file itself starts with an XML tag.

This causes two problems:

- LibreOffice does not read the XML file (it can read HTML files, but not XHTML).
- I am unable to copy and paste the equations into a document editor such as LibreOffice with the goal of subsequent conversion into .doc, because .doc files do not support MathML.

The eLyXer help page mentions an option to only use simple math, but there is no option to set math equations to output as images. And I already set *Document > Settings > Output > Math equations > Format: images* in LyX, which presumably is saved in the lyx document somewhere.

A web search did not come up with any solutions.

Comment: do you want _doc_ finally or the newer _docx_ format? (Getting the latter from MathML is much easier as for example word accepts MathML on paste (and comes with conversion files for batch operations).